# Eclipse running previous programs

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem running programs on eclipse. It's not running any new program.It's stuck on few last projects I previously ran. Overtime I'm trying to run a new program it runs another program that I'm done working on. I don't know what's causing it. I tried everything in my knowledge but nothing seems to be useful. If anyone can help me, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Do you assume that we know all your knowledge and thus what you already tried in detail?

Answer (score -1):

Don't click on Run button in eclipse it sometime run the cached program i.e., already runned programmed
It is not a good practice
being a experienced eclipse user I can advise you to try to right click on your program after saving it then click Run As option and further option(optoin vary like in JSE program it shows java Application and in JEE program it shows server option)
hope you will try this and it can solve your problem

Comment: Thank you. It appears to be helping for now.